# How do I access an error if I use ngf-select with only single file support and the element not on a form?

Tags: ng-file-upload

Here is the HTML code example

```
<div class="button" ngf-select="upload($file)" ng-model="file" name="file" 
                    ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ngf-accept="'image/*'" 
                    ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
                    ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">
      Select
</div>
```

Any ideas?